# 2 page, page turn effect creation

Tags: cocos2d-x

trying to achieve a simple page turn effect where turning page is pivoted from center of screen i.e. just like a open book. I have completed half of the effect but come across a problem. Here's what I'm doing so far...

1) New scene at back (2 col)
2) Old scene at front (2 col)
3) Squish right hand col of old scene to center to reveal right hand side of new scene.

This is where I now have a problem... the next step would be to unsquish new scene on top of old scene on left hand side, but the new scene is currently behind the old. I think I need to some how achieve the following...

1) new scene right side at back
2) old scene right at front
3) new scene left side at front
4) old scene left at back

Then should be a case of pre setting widths and adjusting appropriately for animation.

Any ideas or pointers on how to achieve this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried CCPageTurn action/transition?

Comment: CCPageTurnTransition is for a animation which turns whole scene as if one page, rather than a open book with center spine...

See this js example of the effect im trying to achieve...

http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs

Comment: page turn uses an sction ccpageturn3d

Comment: Ive tried playing with CCActionPageTurn3D to somehow achieve the effect mentioned above using two nodes (node 1 being page 1 and 2, and node 2 being page 3 and 4) but seem to be getting nowhere fast.